# Not able to send an object with netty

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I've used some examples to send and receive strings and they have worked perfectly. The thing is I have tried to adapt the code(reading the api and examples) to send serializable objects and they dont work. I don't get any error message, channel read method is never invoked so server never gets the message. I read it could be related to some kind of delimeter, but I can't find any clue regarding it

Here is the code, i won't include handler added and removed because they work

Server initiaizer

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel arg0) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = arg0.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ObjectDecoder(null));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new ChatServerHandler());
}
```

Channel read

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, Message message)
        throws Exception {
    Channel incoming = arg0.channel();
    System.out.println("received "+ message.getContent() + "from " + message.getSender() + "\r\n" );            

}
```

Run server

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException{
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try{
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
        .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new ChatServerInitializer());         
        bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

    }
```

And here is the client

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel arg0) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = arg0.pipeline();


    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ObjectDecoder(null));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new ChatClientHandler());

}
```

and the main (server says client connected)

```
public void run(){
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                .group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChatClientInitializer());

            Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host,port).sync().channel();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setReceiver("user");
            message.setSender("user 2");
                    try {
                        message.setContent(in.readLine());

                        channel.write(message);

                        System.out.println("Sent " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Last, the message class without get/set

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String content;
public Message(String sender, String receiver, String content){     
    this.setSender(sender);
    this.setReceiver(receiver);
    this.setContent(content);       
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ChannelFuture returned from the write operation. I bet it was failed.

Comment: You are right sir, it did fail. Do you have any clue regarding why would it fail? i think im writing it the right way and the cause method is throwing null

Comment: if it was failed there should be a Throwable. Can you show the stacktrace ?

Comment: it wouldn't throw anything or I don't know the right way to catch it. i am trying to catch any exception and it won't catch anything. Also I ask for isDone() and it says false so maybe that is the reason why I am not getting any exception. Thanks in advance

Comment: I wrote a cycle afterwards while(!future.isDone()) (future is the channelfuture that write returned, and it never comes out.

Comment: Now I see... you need to call channel.writeAndFlush(..) to actually flush it out to the socket. See the apidocs ;)